# Can I play music from my UPnP NAS with VLC on Android?

Tags: vlc

Can I play music from my UPnP NAS with VLC on Android? And if so, how do I find my UPnP device from within VLC?

I'm on the latest beta VLC for Android on a Nexus 4.

Comment: See the Android column on the table at https://wiki.videolan.org/Mobile_Features/

Comment: @HidekiAI according to the page you linked, VLC has implemented support for UPnP/DLNA in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

No I don't think you can do that directly with VLC.
But you could use another app like [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp&hl=da) or [UPnPlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cx.hoohol.silanoid), they are made for the purpose.

Comment: UPnPlay has the strangest interface of all Android apps ever. I'd go with BubbleUPnP.

Comment: I personally like Slick UPnP app.

Comment: From version 2.0 on, VLC for Android seems to support UPnP.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can play music with VLC but only through another app. I did it like this:

- Downloaded [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) on your Android device of course :)
- When you open the `Es File Explorer` you will see 3 icons top center (Local, PC and Cloud): Click on the middle one (PC icon)
  [image]
- A new page just opened. Bottom left corner click on new:
  [image]
- After that just fill in the necessary fields and save. Now you can brows through you NAS and listen to all the music and even watch movies if you have any:
  [image]